# Dagger 2 constructor injection in kotlin with Named arguments

Tags: android, dependency-injection, kotlin, dagger-2

I have this dependency:

```
@Singleton
class SpiceMix @Inject constructor(@field:[Named("oregano")] private val oregano: Spice,
                                   @field:[Named("sage")] private val sage: Spice,
                                   @field:[Named("rosemary")] private val rosemary: Spice)
```

And a module to fulfill its dependencies:

```
@Module
class SpiceModule {

    @Provides
    @Named("oregano")
    @Singleton
    fun provideOregano(): Spice = Oregano()

    @Provides
    @Named("sage")
    @Singleton
    fun provideSage(): Spice = Sage()

    @Provides
    @Named("rosemary")
    @Singleton
    fun provideRosemary(): Spice = Rosemary()
```

The `SpiceMix` is then injected in various locations of my app.

However, this does not compile and I get an error:

```
Spice cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method
```

I think the @Named annotations do not quite work in my constructor signature. I am not quite sure how I can make it work.

Note: this compiles fine if I ditch the Named annotations and change the types of the constructor parameters to their concrete forms. However, Spice is an interface, and I need it for mocking purposes in my tests.

What can I do?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You want to annotate the constructor parameters if you're doing constructor injection, and not the fields - use the `@param:` annotation target:

```
@Singleton
class SpiceMix @Inject constructor(@param:Named("oregano") private val oregano: Spice,
                                   @param:Named("sage") private val sage: Spice,
                                   @param:Named("rosemary") private val rosemary: Spice)
```

Edit: actually, since the resolution order for annotation targets is

> - param;
> - property;
> - field.

according to the [docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/annotations.html#annotation-use-site-targets), having no annotation target should also annotate the parameter of the constructor. So you can just drop the target altogether:

```
@Singleton
class SpiceMix @Inject constructor(@Named("oregano") private val oregano: Spice,
                                   @Named("sage") private val sage: Spice,
                                   @Named("rosemary") private val rosemary: Spice)
```

Comment: Yes!! Thank you! Worked like a charm

Comment: Hey! Good to hear, see my edited answer as well - I realised there's an even simpler solution.

Comment: Ha! If only I had just tried it the good ol' Java way, it would've worked off the bat. Nevertheless, today I learned! Thanks.