# How do I inject two String values using Dagger 2?

Tags: java, dagger-2

I'm trying to use Dagger 2 dependency injection and one of my requirements is that I be able to inject two string values into the created object.  The code below is my attempt to do that.  The values for brandName and modelNumber are never set in the created coffeeMaker (the printlns print null/null).

Can anyone see what I'm doing incorrectly here?

Thanks

```
package com.so;

import dagger.BindsInstance;
import dagger.Component;
import dagger.Module;
import dagger.Provides;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Named;

public class MyProblem {
    interface ICoffeeMaker {
        String getBrandName();
        String getModelNumber();
    }

    class BrandXCoffeeMaker implements  ICoffeeMaker {
        @Inject public String brandName;
        @Inject public String modelNumber;
        @Override public String getBrandName() { return brandName; }
        @Override public String getModelNumber() { return modelNumber; }
    }

    @Module
    class DaggerModule {
        @Provides ICoffeeMaker provideCoffeeMaker() { return new BrandXCoffeeMaker();}
    }

    @Component(modules = DaggerModule.class)
    interface CoffeeMakerComponent {
        ICoffeeMaker getCoffeeMaker();

        @Component.Builder
        interface Builder {
            @BindsInstance
            Builder brandName(String brandName);
            @BindsInstance
            Builder modelNumber(String modelNumber);
            Builder daggerModule(DaggerModule module);
            CoffeeMakerComponent build();
        }
    }

    public MyProblem() {
        ICoffeeMaker coffeeMaker = DaggerMyProblem_CoffeeMakerComponent
                .builder()
                .brandName("Brand Name Here")
                .modelNumber("Model Number Here")
                .daggerModule(new DaggerModule())
                .build()
                .getCoffeeMaker();

        System.out.println(coffeeMaker.getBrandName());
        System.out.println(coffeeMaker.getModelNumber());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        new MyProblem();
    }
}
```

(Edit: code formatting)

Comment: You should be getting a compile time error like `string is bound multiple times`. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3tIvekCTSJg

Comment: I know @sonnet.  In my actual program I'm getting that but when I went to make a simple example I don't get that compile error.  Also I had to add the daggerModule() setter or it wouldn't compile.   I don't have to  "new DaggerModule()" in my actual program.

Comment: You need qualifiers to bind multiple objects of the same type. See the Qualifiers section on the [Dagger dev guide](https://dagger.dev/dev-guide).

Comment: Thank you @Nicolas  I needed to read the documentation more diligently.  The problem came down the fact that I did not have "@Qualifier" annotations on the annotations I created to differentiate these fields.   Again, a difference between the code I posted and the real code I was trying to develop.  If you want to post an answer saying "Annotate your BindsInstance builder methods with annotations marked "@Qualifier" annotation" I'll accept.  Thanks

Comment: I'm glad you could work it out!

Comment: Should be marked as duplicate. [Dagger2 - How to use @Named with @BindsInstance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54115182/dagger2-how-to-use-named-with-bindsinstance)