# Dagger module depends on another module

Tags: android, dagger-2, dagger

I'm new to DI and Dagger.

I have this dependency graph in the Android project:

```
@Module(includes=[Module1, Module2, Module3]) ClassAModule

@Module(includes=[classAModule, Module4]) ClassBModule

@Module(includes=[ClassBModule]) ClassCModule

@Module(includes=[ClassBModule]) ClassDModule
```

Here's how `Module3` looks like

```
@Module
class Module3 {
    @Provides
    fun provideUrl(): Url{
        return ...
    }
}
```

`Module3`'s Url is required by `ClassAModule`, 
But I want `ClassCModule` and `ClassDModule` to be able to provide different Url to `ClassAModule`
how should I approach this?

Comment: `includes` is for including other modules into your module. What is `para1`, `para2`, and so on ? They don't look like modules.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce I'll edit and make it bit clear. They should be modules.

Comment: Use `@Named` parameters to provide different url of the same "type"

Comment: You can create a separate component for each use case and show ModuleAClass, <ModuleClassYouNeedToGetUrl> class as the component modules.

Comment: @sonnet thx. could you elaborate more?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48442623/dagger-2-constructor-injection-in-kotlin-with-named-arguments

Comment: @sonnet thx but in my case there's a chain of dependencies. A-> B -> C/D, and C/D needs to provide something A needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get specific url for any module, you need to define **annotation** on provider method.

**Example**

```
    @Provides
    @Room
    fun provideRoomWordDataSource(): WordDataSource {
        return RoomWordDataSource()
    }

    @Provides
    @Firestore
    fun provideFirestoreWordDataSource(): WordDataSource {
        return FirestoreWordDataSource()
    }

    @Singleton
    class WordRepository
    @Inject constructor(
        @Room private val room: WordDataSource,
        @Firestore private val firestore: WordDataSource
    ) : Repository<String, Word>(rx, rm), WordDataSource {
    }
```

First two **provider** method has define **WordDataSource** instance of two difference class and define with two different annotation **@Room** and **@Firestore**.

To get two different **WordDataSource** in **WordRepository**, have just used **@Room** and **@Firestore** **annotation** in its **constructor**.

Enjoy the annotation power in Dagger. :) 
Please feel free, if you need more details from me.